# NUnit - Getter Setter Method Testing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I am trying to test out a getter and setter method as follows

```
  public class GetToken
     {
         public string TokenStatusCode { get; set; }
         public AccountPrimary TokenKey { get; set; }
     }
```

with the NUnit code as follows

```
    [Test]
    public void GetToken_StatusCode()
    {
        TestHelperGetterSetter<GetToken, string>(new StackFrame().GetMethod(), 
        "TokenStatusCode", "RipSnorter");
    }

    [Test]
    public void GetToken_TokenIden()
    {
        TestHelperGetterSetter<GetToken, object>(new StackFrame().GetMethod(),
        "TokenKey", 77);
    }
```

With a helper as follows

```
  private void TestHelperGetterSetter<TAttr, TProp>(MethodBase method,
                 string argName, TProp expectedValue)
    {
        object[] customAttributes = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttr), false);

        Assert.AreEqual(1, customAttributes.Count());

        TAttr attr = (TAttr)customAttributes[0];

        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = attr.GetType().GetProperty(argName);

        Assert.IsNotNull(propertyInfo);
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(TProp), propertyInfo.PropertyType);
        Assert.IsTrue(propertyInfo.CanRead);
        Assert.IsTrue(propertyInfo.CanWrite);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedValue, (TProp)propertyInfo.GetValue(attr, null));
    }
```

Everytime I run the test the test fails with the result as below

```
 Expected: 1
 But was:  0
```

Can someone let me know, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `StackFrame()` method (its C'tor) has any attribute? it seems that the test fail at this line: `Assert.AreEqual(1, customAttributes.Count());`

Comment: @OldFox StackFrame() initializes a new instance of the System.Diagnostics.StackFrame class, does this answer your question?? Do you think this is the right approach to test the Getter Setter Method??

Comment: yes, it's answered my question. your test failed because the C''tor of `StackFrame` has no attributes. what behaviour are you trying to verify in your test?

Comment: @OldFox I am basically trying to test if the method can read / write / store information. Does this makes sense?

Comment: so do the simplest solution. put an data in the property and then do the assert against the property.

Comment: @OldFox I understand, Simple way should have been good. lol. However, Can you let me know how I can fix the issue I am having above?

Comment: remove the attribute section. change the method signature to get `PropertyInfo` instead of `MethodBase` and then pass the `PropertyInfo` of the property you want to test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour you are trying to verify is "I can read and write data from my class properties". The easiest way to achieve this behaviour is:

```
[setup]
public void testInit()
{
     target = new GetToken();
}

[Test]
public void GetToken_StatusCode()
{
    var expectedValue = "RipSnorter";
    target.TokenStatusCode = expectedValue;
    Assert.AreEquals(expectedValue, target.TokenStatusCode);
}
```

do the same thing this `TokenKey` ....

if you still want to use your method, you need to remove:

```
    object[] customAttributes = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttr), false);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, customAttributes.Count());
    TAttr attr = (TAttr)customAttributes[0];
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = attr.GetType().GetProperty(argName);
```

and then pass `PropertyInfo` instead of `MethodBase` (change the method signature)

Comment: I am 100% with you, however, I am wondering, how do I change `TestHelperGetterSetter<GetToken, object>(new StackFrame().GetMethod(), "TokenKey", 77);`   if I change the signature to the PropertyInfo??